# how to transition animated strips and change the direction of animation CSS?

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to transition an animation. I have a button that when you hover it animates the background size to move the stripes.

as of right now the animation moves towards the right, but I want it to move towards the left.

The second issue is that when I move the mouse off of the button and no longer hovering it I want it to transition and move to the left.

CODE:

```
.btn2{
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #3B8A7D, #3B8A7D 
    9px, #54BC9B 9px, #54BC9B 18px);
    background-size: 20px 10px;
    border: solid 2px #54BC9B;
 }

.btn2:hover{
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #3B8A7D, #3B8A7D 10px, #54BC9B 10px, #54BC9B 18px);
    background-size: 150% 100%;
    border: solid 2px #54BC9B;
    animation: greenstripes 0.5s linear;
 }


@keyframes greenstripes {
   0% {
       background-position: 0 0;
   }
   100% {
       background-position: -75px 0px;
   }
   transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that it's impossible to achieve scrolling to the left on both onmousein (hover) and onmouseout through CSS only. You could achieve it with javascript. I added CSS code for the animation though, where I do a transition on `background-position-x`.

```css
.btn2{
    --button-primary-background-color: #54BC9B;
    --button-secondary-background-color: #3B8A7D;

    background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
       var(--button-secondary-background-color),
       var(--button-secondary-background-color) 10px,
       var(--button-primary-background-color) 10px,
       var(--button-primary-background-color) 20px);
    border: solid 2px var(--button-primary-background-color);
    background-position-x: 100px;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;

    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;

    transition: background-position-x 1s;
 }

.btn2:hover{
    background-position-x: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn2" value="Hover me" />
```